# Singing seated on the floor: Best position?

Tags: voice

I use to sing a lot in large groups of people who are seated on the floor (just on some soft pad or similar). I always find myself not being able to sing well because of the position in which I sit, with my legs crossed. This causes that I can't sing as high and as loud as when I stand, for instance.

Is there a better (and comfortable) position in which I can sit to be able to better sing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rest on your knees with your pad below it (imagine someone on their knees in prayer, but with a pillow to cushion their knees). This would allow you to keep your diaphragm, neck and head straight but also keep your knees comfortable with the floor.

Sitting with your legs crossed is definitely going to make it more difficult for you to push project your voice.

Comment: How do you arrange your feet so that the ankles don't start hurting after half an hour? I don't manage to put them straight below me, my ankle is not flexible enough for that :( Maybe I'll need a bit thicker pad...

Comment: I would arrange my ankles so that each was turned inward, with the left foot cupping the right. Something like this: http://cf.ltkcdn.net/yoga/images/std/121896-283x425-Hero_pose2.jpg

Comment: Again, sitting on the ground is not ideal for singing. Is there a reason why people aren't sitting in chairs?

Comment: Yep, there is. It's a meditative church services (Taizé-kind). I know it's not ideal, but I want to get the best out of it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Fascinating - I should have guessed that! No problem. I would definitely recommend some seated yoga for you and the rest of congregation. Google the "Hero Pose" (or Virasana) or the "Easy Pose" (or Sukhasana). Good starters.